# How can I make off-center rotate animations in android look similar in portrait and landscape?

Tags: android, animation, imageview, drawable, image-rotation

I have a screen that has a few images and one of them has a neat animation on it that looks awesome in portrait.

Awesome animation in portrait - rotate_anim_port.png -  in [HERE](http://nicedice.scdevtesting.com/anim/)

It does not look so awesome in landscape.

Animation in landscape - rotate_anim_land.png - in above.

I am implementing the off-center rotation animation in this way because I have several imageviews with drawable resources of the same size stacked together in a frameview to keep them all in relatively the same spot, but able to scale to whatever size the frameview is.

It looks bad because the view in which the `RotateAnimation(fromDegrees, toDegrees, pivotXType, pivotXValue, pivotYType, pivotYValue)` is basing its pivotValues off of is not the same size as the image inside the view.  When in portrait, the image is virtually the same size as the view, but in landscape the difference is apparent.

I have been trying and failing to get the positions from both the view and the drawn image inside of it to use to math up the proper pivotValues to pass in code.

Here is the code for the activity:

```
package com.namespace;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AnimationDemoActivity extends Activity {

// piviotValues if the view is the exact size of the drawable.
final float pivotXType = 0.3280274656679151f;
final float pivotYValue = 0.5060137457044674f;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
ImageView outside, inside;
RotateAnimation anim, anim2;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    outside = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    inside = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    outside.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
    inside.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

    // somewhere in here, code to recalculate pivotValues to adjust for the
    // size of the actual view the images are inside of

    anim = new RotateAnimation(0, 359, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            pivotXType, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, pivotYValue);
    anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    anim.setDuration(2000);

    anim2 = new RotateAnimation(0, 359, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            pivotXType, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, pivotYValue);
    anim2.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    anim2.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    anim2.setDuration(750);

    mHandler.postDelayed(doRotation, 2500);
}

private Runnable doRotation = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        outside.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
        inside.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
        outside.startAnimation(anim);
        inside.startAnimation(anim2);
    }
};
}
```

and here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10sp" >

<ImageSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/imageSwitcher1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center" >
</ImageSwitcher>

<ImageSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/imageSwitcher2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center" >
</ImageSwitcher>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/dwdg_outside_arrow" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/dwdg_inside_arrow" >
    </ImageView>
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[Here](http://nicedice.scdevtesting.com/anim/) is runnable apk - AnimationDemo.apk and zipped project - AnimationDemo.zip

Am I crazy for doing it this way?  Am I totally overlooking something?  What do?

Comment: How did you calculate **pivotXType** and **pivotYValue** ?

Comment: Those are for the position of the centerpoint of the overlay in relation to the background drawable.  The pivotYValue is at 0.5060137457044674f, or 50%ish of the height of the drawable, thus the center.  The pivotXType is at 33%ish of the width of the drawable, thus to the left of center.  If you wanted it to the right of the center, then you would make it 66%ish.  I had to do it that way because you will never know exactly what size the drawable or overlay will be once it is put up as pixels on the screen, but you will always know their sizes relative to each other.

Comment: To whit, all I did was find the pixel centerpoint where I wanted the animation to rotate on top of my background in my raw image file, and then get the ratio of that over the pixel size of the whole image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it figured out.  Of course, it was a one line fix.  Adding the attribute `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to the ImageViews makes the view shrink to the size of the drawable resource and make the animation work properly.